# Is it possible to select a column without aggregating it?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for a way to display a column in my table without aggregating it (column `store`)

```
SELECT id, name, max(cost), store 
FROM test
group by 1,2,4
```

But in the table im using there are some row that shares the same id,name,license **with different** machine, and Ideally I'd like to get in return only a single row, with `max(cost)`, if they share the same first 2 columns and only display the last column - without using it to group by.

actual outcome:

| id | name | max(cost) | store |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe | 30 | store1 |
| 1 | Joe | 50 | store2 |

but my desired result will be:

| id | name | max(cost) | store |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe | 50 | store2 |

Can it even be done?

Comment: Any reason you do not want to use aggregation ?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the row with the maximum cost.  A typical method uses `row_number()`;

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, name order by cost desc) as seqnum
      from test t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

No aggregation is needed.

You can also use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from test t
where t.cost = (select max(t2.cost)
                from test t2
                where t2.id = t.id
               );
```